# Finite representations of $\mathbb{C}[x]$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $\mathbb{C}[x]$ be the ring of polynomials with complex coefficients, how can I find any finite representation of $\mathbb{C}[x]$?

Comment: What do you mean? Just a finite-dimensional $\mathbf C[x]$-module?

Answer (score 3):

A complex representation $V$ of $\Bbb C[x]$ will be a ring homomorphism $\Bbb C[x]\to{\rm End}_{\Bbb C}(V)$.

What do you know about outbound homomorphisms from a polynomial ring? Well, $R[x]$ comes with a universal property: $x$ can go anywhere and where it goes determines the homomorphism.

If you want to classify all isomorphism types of representations: decompose $V$ into eigenspaces and invoke the Jordan-normal form of $A$, so it suffices to explore the action of Jordan blocks.